# How to initialize an empty pointer by reflect

Tags: pointers, reflection, go

This is a very straight forward question.

How do you implement `Initialize()` below with `reflect`?
Or is this possible?

```
func Initialize(v interface{}) {
    // ... some reflection code
}

type MyType struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    var val *MyType

    // val is nil before initialize
    Initialize(val)
    // val is now &MyType{Name: ""}

    // ...
}
```

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
func Initialize(v interface{}) {
  rv := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem()
  rv.Set(reflect.New(rv.Type().Elem()))
}
```

This function must be called with a pointer to the value to set:

```
Initialize(&val)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/rcIeNGe3Jb)

The code in this answer panics if the argument type is not a pointer to a pointer.  Depending on your use, you might want to check the reflect [value](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Kind) [kind](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type.Kind) before calling Elem().

Comment: So there is no way to implement `Initialize` so `Initialize(val)` works, right?

Comment: Correct.  That's because arguments are passed by value in Go.